# print to an other session's controlling terminal

Tags: c, terminal, embedded-linux, process-group

Why does `echo hello > /dev/pts/xxx` work (here xxx refers to another session's controlling terminal)?

With default setting, a process of the background process group of this session will get a signal SIGTTOU when it tries to write to stdout (here stdout refers to the controlling terminal), because the terminal driver will check whether this process belongs to the foreground process group.

So how does the terminal driver tolerate an output from another session's process? What happened there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why a process can redirect its output to an other session's controlling terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288353/why-a-process-can-redirect-its-output-to-an-other-sessions-controlling-terminal)

Comment: Yeah, I asked that, too. But no clear answer, so I made another description.

Comment: The lack of a clear answer over there might be due to the lack of the code sample.